# Python Tkinter scrollbar in canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, frame, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to do a scrollbar on the right side of the canvas ( the window ), but the scrollbar won't even show when plotting. What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *

# create canvas
root = Tk()
root.title("Aktieköp")
root.configure(background="white")
frame=Frame(root, width=1100, height=1000)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
canvas=Canvas(frame,bg="white",width=1100,height=1000)

# my photo
photo = PhotoImage(file="aktier.gif")
label0 = Label(frame, image = photo, bg="white"). grid(row=0, column=0)

# create scrollbar

scrollbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
frame.config(width=1100,height=1000)
frame.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
frame.pack(side=RIGHT,expand=True,fill=Y)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the layout managers wrong:

1. Do not use `grid()` and `pack()` to layout children of a widget:

   1. `frame.grid()` and `frame.pack()` ==> `root` now uses two layout managers and frame needs to be mapped by two managers
   2. `label0.grid()` and `scrollbar.pack()` ==> `frame` uses two layout managers
2. `canvas` is not mapped by `grid` or `pack` at all, so how you can see and draw on it I don't know.